# Symmetric difference of sets and convergence in integration.

Tags: measure-theory, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},m)$ be a space of measure and $f_n,f \in L^1(m)$ such as $||f_n - f||_1 \rightarrow 0.$ Suppose that we also have $A_n,A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $m(A_n \triangle A) \rightarrow 0.$

I want to prove that $\displaystyle \int_{A_n}f_n dm \rightarrow \int_A f dm.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|_1}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
\begin{align*}
  \abs{\int_{A_n} f_n \, dm - \int_A f\, dm} &\le \abs{\int_{A_n} (f_n- f)\, dm} + \abs{\int_{A_n} f\, dm - \int_A f \, dm}\\
&\le \int_{A_n} \abs{f_n-f}\, dm + \int_{A_n \Delta A} \abs{f}\, dm\\
&\le \norm{f_n -f} + \norm{f \cdot \chi_{A_n \Delta A}}\\
  &\to 0 
\end{align*}
Where $\chi_{A_n \Delta A}$ denotes the charateristic function. For the second term on the second to last line, note that $\chi_{A_n \Delta A}f \to 0$ almost everywhere and $\abs f$ is a integrable bound, hence the bounded convergence theorem gives $\norm{f \chi_{A_n \Delta A}} \to 0$.